# How retrieve the name of specific dictionary - Ansible

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-facts

I need help to retrieve only the name of the Virtual Machines of my ESXI Host.

```
- name: VM-FACTS
  vmware_vm_facts:
    hostname: "{{ ansible_hostname }}"
    username: "{{ ansible_user }}"
    password: "{{ ansible_password }}"
    validate_certs: False
  delegate_to: localhost
  register: vmfacts

- name: Debug
  debug:
    var: vmfacts.virtual_machines
```

Output of the variable:

```
ok: [xxxxx] => {
    "vmfacts.virtual_machines": {
        "001-MV-Test": {
            "cluster": null,
            "esxi_hostname": "xxxxx",
            "guest_fullname": "Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7 (64-bit)",
            "ip_address": "10.252.130.196",
            "mac_address": [
                "00:50:56:b3:c5:b0"
            ],
            "power_state": "poweredOn",
            "uuid": "4233910e-4fde-7d1b-765d-b748bf9d1cd9",
            "vm_network": {
                "00:50:56:b3:c5:b0": {
                    "ipv4": [
                        "10.252.130.196"
                    ],
                    "ipv6": [
                        "fe80::250:56ff:feb3:c5b0"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want to have only the name of the virtual machine (001-MV-Test). Because, I want to retrieve more information with vmware_guest_facts.

Thanks!

Comment: Does that mean you are not familiar with Jinja2 templates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this the code that you're looking for?

```
- debug: msg="{{ item.key }}"
  loop: "{{ vmfacts.virtual_machines|dict2items }}"
```

Comment: Thank you Vladimir!