# Ansible vmware_vm_facts: get mac address for a specific VM and write it to existing inventory

Tags: ansible, virtual-machine, vmware

I have to goals with my plabook:

a) get mac address from a specific VM running on vsphere
b) add it to my inventory file

My test environment is:
-Vsphere 6.5
-Ansible 2.7 running on Centos 7.6

I have been able to make point a) following this post [How retrieve the name of specific dictionary - Ansible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53453718/how-retrieve-the-name-of-specific-dictionary-ansible)

Playbook:

```
# Deploy a guest from a template*  
- hosts: 127.0.0.1  
  vars:
    vcenter_hostname: virtvcsami1.virtlab.local  
    vcenter_user: administrator@vsphere.local  
    vcenter_pass: Esxilab!1  
    vcenter_datastore: vsanDatastore  
    vcenter_datacenter: DatacenterMI  
  tasks:  
  - name: Gather VMware guest facts  
    vmware_vm_facts:  
      validate_certs: False  
      hostname: "{{ vcenter_hostname }}"  
      username: "{{ vcenter_user }}"  
      password: "{{ vcenter_pass }}"  
      vm_type: vm  
    delegate_to: localhost  
    register: vm_guest_facts  

  - debug: msg="{{ item.value.mac_address }}"  
    loop: "{{ vm_guest_facts.virtual_machines|dict2items }}"
```

but now I still have two problems to solve:

Problem 1)

Playbook gets ALL virtual machines while I need to get just a VM named "testvm"

> [root@nlnxmi1 testvmcdromiso]# ansible-playbook getvminfo.yml
>
> PLAY [127.0.0.1]  ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
>   TASK [Gathering Facts]   *****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
>   ok: [127.0.0.1]
>   TASK [Gather VMware guest facts]   *******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
>   ok: [127.0.0.1 -> localhost]
>   TASK [debug]   ***************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
>   ok: [127.0.0.1] => (item={'key': u'kubemst01', 'value': {u'guest_fullname': u'CentOS 7 (64-bit)', u'vm_network': {u'00:50:56:be:de:b9': {u'ipv4': [u'192.168.40.31'], u'ipv6': [u'fe80::250:56ff:febe:deb9']}, u'52:54:00:62:fe:fe': {u'ipv4': [u'192.168.122.1'], u'ipv6': []}}, u'cluster': u'VirtlabMI', u'esxi_hostname': u'virtesxmi3.virtlab.local', u'mac_address': [u'00:50:56:be:de:b9'], u'power_state': u'poweredOn', u'ip_address': u'192.168.40.31', u'uuid': u'423e7580-1ca4-a6ca-5cb4-5b8fa963d527'}}) => {
>       "msg": [
>           "00:50:56:be:de:b9"
>       ]
>   }
>
> ok: [127.0.0.1] => (item={'key': u'testvm', 'value': {u'guest_fullname': >u'CentOS 7 (64-bit)', u'vm_network': {}, u'cluster': u'VirtlabMI', >u'esxi_hostname': u'virtesxmi1.virtlab.local', u'mac_address': >[u'00:50:56:be:a3:a0'], u'power_state': u'poweredOn', u'ip_address': u'', >u'uuid': u'423e8645-ca2a-1097-2e1c-624810a461d1'}}) => {
>      "msg": [
>          "00:50:56:be:a3:a0"
>      ]
>   }
>   ......

Problem 2)

Add mac address to existing inventory file or, if not possible, at least in some file

I tried adding the following code at the end:

```
  - set_fact: vm_mac_address="prova"  

  - name: Register host to Inventory  
    lineinfile:  
      path: /etc/ansible/testvmcdromiso/inventory  
      regexp: '(testvm)'  
      line: '\1 macaddres={{ vm_mac_address }}'  
      backrefs: yes
```

> [root@nlnxmi1 testvmcdromiso]# cat inventory
>   [testhost]
>   testvm macaddress=prova

but as you can see I just used a "fixed" string instead I need to get the mac address from the running vm but never figure it out even after 2 days of attempts :(

I'm just a beginner with ansible. Could you please help me?

best
Marco

Answer (score 0):

> Playbook gets ALL virtual machines while I need to get just a VM named "testvm"

That's not a problem. It looks like the `vmware_vm_facts` module returns a dictionary, so just ask for the vm you want:

```
  - debug: msg="{{ vm_guest_facts.virtual_machines['testvm'].mac_address }}"
```

> Add mac address to existing inventory file or, if not possible, at least in some file

Since you now know how to retrieve the MAC address, you modify your `lineinfile` task make use of that information:

```
  - name: Register host to Inventory  
    lineinfile:  
      path: /etc/ansible/testvmcdromiso/inventory  
      regexp: '(testvm)'  
      line: '\1 macaddres={{ vm_guest_facts.virtual_machines['testvm'].mac_address }}'  
      backrefs: yes
```